# Why strange crash with mapview happen?

Tags: objective-c

I have a very simple app. 1 navigationController with 2 viewControllers.

The first view has only a button. 
The second view has a map view (MKMapView). 
I checked show currentlocation property of this map view
I created outlet and then connect everything by using Builder Interface.

In the dealloc method of the second one, I set nil to delegate of mapview, and then release mapview outlet.

mapView.delegate = nil;
[mapview release];

When I tap the button in view1, view2 will be loaded, and then I tap back button. If I do it normally, everything works well. But If I do it very quickly, repeat many times. The app will be crashed. 
If I do not release mapView or I do not check showcurrentlocation property, app works well.

I can't figure out why this happen. Anyone helps me solve this problem. Thanks so much !

Answer (score 2):

My fix in controller class was to ..

```
(void)dealloc
{
  mapView.showUserLocation = NO;  // Work around bug in MKMapView
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try launching your app via Instruments with Zombie instrument added. It should show you overreleased object. You'd also should add the Allocations instrument with VM tracker to see how memory consumption goes over time. This way you'd get your answer very quick.

p.s. more code would help better.

Comment: I have investigated the problem, and the answer is: That's a bug of MKMapView. We can fix this by: create static instant for MKMapView object, or you call delay method for releasing mapView about 4 seconds.